# Can we run a loop in a column of mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, facebook-login, login-control

Through php, I have to take input of user name and then search for the same in column named as useername of mysql table.

If username matches, it looks for matching the password of the same row, so is it possible to run a loop that tries to match the data?

If yes what should it be like?  If not please tell me some alternative.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need to run a loop

Comment: i need to run a loop to check if username is there and if that doesnt exist in my database it will go for else and will display wrong username so is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please also read about escaping and SQL-Injections when you try to create a login. Otherwhise it would be vulnerable for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about SQL queries, I really can't answer any better than that. SQL is used to select data from database, you could use a command like:

```
Select employeeID from table where username = 'user' and password = 'password'
```

If you get a record return there has been a match. Essentially, if you do a query like "give me data that matches this query" the database server does loop over all the dta and tries to find any row the matches. To it already loops over all the data, there is no need to do it by hand.

Again: Please learn something about SQL. By the question you are asking it's obvious you are missing a very basic understanding. This will kill your time (trying useless things) and possibly harm others (if you ever let you code run in the public).

Comment: and if the username doesnt exist how to display 'username doesnt exist in database' statement

Comment: @user1892302 - if username will not exists then you will not get any rows. you can check row count using `mysql_num_rows()` function if you are working with `MySQL` database

Comment: @Pankit Kapadia hey will die finctn will do the job if username doesnt match?

Comment: @user1892302 - `die()` function stops the execution of the script.

Comment: @user1892302 - have a look at [this link](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html)

Comment: and srry if i am annoying you but @Pnamit s, its not possible to run a loop in a column right?

Comment: It is possible, you would return the column to the php scritp first for processing there.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a SQL request like this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE passwd = sr8stk23kel796ki345k54k2
```

Comment: of course, `sr8stk23kel796ki345k54k2` is not my md5 or sha* encrypted password ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE `name` = '$variable_containing_name' AND `password` = '$password'"
```

if it returns row then the match was found 
where `name` and `password` is columns names and you need two variables that contains username and password you want to search.
you don't need to loop in php sql will do the job

Comment: and if the username doesnt exist how to display 'username doesnt exist in database' statement